# pyopencl on Intel(R) Iris(R) Plus Graphics

Tags: python, pycharm, pyopencl

I'm getting the following error:

```
"Build on <pyopencl.Device 'Intel(R) Iris(R) Plus Graphics' on 'Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics' at 0x1cf4da041e0>:
**error**: use of type 'double' requires cl_khr_fp64 extension to be enabled. "
```

I'm using **pyopencl 2021.2.6**. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Error message says it all:

> ...use of type 'double' requires cl_khr_fp64 extension to be enabled.

Add in the first line of the OpenCL file / code the following line to enable double floating point type:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But Im facing an error once after entering the above code. The error im having is "unsupported OpenCL extension 'cl_khr_fp64' - ignoring #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable". Afraid will there be anything like that a system doesn't support OpenCL, any idea?

Comment: It looks like the GPU does not support double floating point. Use different GPU or if possible change algorithm to use float.

Comment: I had the same problem: NVIDIA RTX works like charm, Intel Iris didn't work at all. Appeared, that Iris does not support double precision at all. https://community.intel.com/t5/GPU-Compute-Software/Iris-Xe-Graphics-can-t-compute-double-precision-floating-point/m-p/1281976